# How can I find out my OpenGL version on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, version

Does this question even make sense?

SFML 2.0 has added a feature whereby you can specify an OpenGL version to use. Is there a terminal command I can run (or otherwise) to find out what version I should be using?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47062/what-is-terminal-command-that-can-show-opengl-version

Comment: How do you define "should be using"?

Comment: No idea, I'm not an expert but @MattPhillips fixed this issue for me.

Comment: @EdwardBird: Then your question is poorly phrased. If you wanted to know what the highest version of OpenGL supported by a system is, you should have *asked* for that. So fix your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To know your OpenGL version in Ubuntu,

Install Glxinfo

```
$sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

To Check OpenGL Version,

```
$glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

You will get the output as follows,

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 7.7.1)
```

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/47062/what-is-terminal-command-that-can-show-opengl-version

Answer (score 2):

There is no "should be using". The version you "should" be using is the minimum version that you want to support. What version that is depends on what hardware you want your program to execute on. If the hardware can't support that version, then your code simply won't run on it. And if you want your code to run on lower versions, then you should have asked for *that* version and written your application against that lower version.

Comment: Well GTX 670MX supports 4.1, but clearly the information you give is not correct, because running SFML with version 3.2 specified causes problems.

Comment: @EdwardBird: What kind of problems? Nicol Bolas is right, and whatever's broken, it should not be due to a higher version being supported than what's requested.